# don't get any responce from openAI model . gives Error: Request failed with status code 429

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, openai-api, chatgpt-api

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

dotenv.config();

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// console.log(process.env.API_KEY)

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = 5001;

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ message: "Welcome to SpinoTech GPT-3" });
})

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = req.body;
        //  console.log(data.data);

         const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: data.data,
            temperature: 0,
            max_tokens: 300,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0.5,
            presence_penalty: 0,
          });
        // console.log(response.data.choices[0].text);
        res.status(200).send({
            bot:response.data.choices[0].text
        })

    } catch (error) {
        // console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`GPT backend is running on port http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
})
```

**when i console log data.data before openai.createCompletion() i can get my massege but after i can't get my massege also i don't even get my responce from openai.createCompletion()**

1st of all i passed an object {data:"my question for chatGPT"} like this data from frontend . and i get the data at backend when i call the post call . but i don't get any responce from the openAI model . it gives some error somthing link this :-

```
Error: Request failed with status code 429
    at createError (F:\web devolopment tutorials\react js file\chatGPT\chatgpt_backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)        
    at settle (F:\web devolopment tutorials\react js file\chatGPT\chatgpt_backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (F:\web devolopment tutorials\react js file\chatGPT\chatgpt_backend\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1',
      Authorization: 'Bearer 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',
      'Content-Length': 130
    },
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"model":"text-davinci-003","prompt":"hh","temperature":0,"max_tokens":300,"top_p":1,"frequency_penalty":0.5,"presence_penalty":0}', 
    url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 130,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.openai.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.openai.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 35,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /v1/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer 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\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 130\r\n' +
      'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/v1/completions',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 429,
      statusMessage: 'Too Many Requests',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 22,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.openai.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 130,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 429,
    statusText: 'Too Many Requests',
    headers: {
      date: 'Mon, 31 Jul 2023 08:47:25 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '222',
      connection: 'close',
      vary: 'Origin',
      'x-request-id': 'e8c4010eede0d3028c80108d480989a0',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '7ef49396dd0b41b6-BOM',
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'post',
      data: '{"model":"text-davinci-003","prompt":"hh","temperature":0,"max_tokens":300,"top_p":1,"frequency_penalty":0.5,"presence_penalty":0}',
      url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions'
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 130,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /v1/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.2.1\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer 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\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 130\r\n' +
        'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/v1/completions',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.openai.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: { error: [Object] }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Comment: What if you change `prompt: data.data,` to `prompt: "This is a test",`. Do you get a response?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

This error message indicates that you have hit your assigned rate limit for the API. This means that you have submitted too many tokens or requests in a short period of time and have exceeded the number of requests allowed.
I guess you are using a free plan that has a low rate limit.

**Solution**

If you are using a free or low-tier plan, consider upgrading to a pay-as-you-go plan that offers a higher rate limit.